# understanding thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was learning about threads in C#. When I was writing some code, I learned to pause a thread, I should call the `Thread.Sleep()` function. It will pause the thread for the time I passed as parameter.

But to abort or start the thread, I need to use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
Thread.CurrentThread.Start()
```

`CurrentThread` is also a `Thread`. So, I was expecting something like this

```
Thread.Sleep()
Thread.Start()
Thread.Abort()
```

or

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
Thread.CurrentThread.Start()
Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep()
```

Why is it different? What is the principle behind this?

I am not sure if it is a valid question or not. If It seems an invalid question to you please let me know, I will remove this question.

Comment: The `CurrentThread` methods are only there because this static property is also of type `Thread`. But semantically it does not make sense. If you can execute `CurrentThread.Start()`, the current thread obviously is already running. `CurrentThread.Abort()` also shouldn't be necessary if you simply return from the thread's entry point method.

Comment: Please never ever ever call `Thread.Abort()` **unless you are trying to forcibly exit your app**. Calling abort can leave the .NET run-time in an invalid state and can corrupt all remaining threads. If you're using `.Abort()` you're doing something wrong and there's always a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Abort()` and `Start()` are instance methods of class `Thread`. You use them to interact with an existing `Thread` instance from the outside e.g. main thread.

`Sleep()` is a static method. You call it from within the running thread's context to cause it to pause.

Comment: yes, clear. but why can't I call sleep method from outside e.g. main thread. I know it is static that is why i can't but why is that. "You call it from within the running thread's context to cause it to pause" why shouldn't i call it from another context using instance of that thread. Actually I want to know the design principle
Is my question is too lame..sorry for that again :(

Comment: @Sadid Khan: Because static methods can also be called on instance methods, but they still get called as static. So if you create a new thread from the main thread and call sleep on it, the main thread will sleep, not the child thread.